# Typo3 FCE refer a field inside a container field

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Here is the screen shot of mapping of my FCE:

[image]

I can refer 'Caption' field by 'field_caption' from the typoscript of 'Link' field.

Here is the typoscript for that:

```
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = field_caption
```

How to refer the 'Image' field which is inside a container field 'Image and alternate text' From the typoscript of 'Link' field?

I tried to refer it directly by using 'field_image', but it is not working.

here is the screen shot:
  [image]

Markup I am trying to map is:

```
    <a href="resources/img/site/demo1.jpg">
      <img src="resources/img/site/demo1.jpg" alt="alternate text" />
      <div class="flex-caption">
        <p>caption text</p>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain what you want to achieve? Do you want to link an image?

Comment: I want to get the value of field_image inside the typoscript of link field.

Comment: @artworkad added screen shot of what I tried.

Comment: So you want to wrap the image with a link right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want to wrap the image with a link. Actually you have to do it the other way round.

[image]

In my case the `span link` has `display:none;` because it's my link placeholder. In your scenario it is `field_link`.

Now click to edit your field_image and click on data processing. Edit TS Code:

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.XY = 200,150
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/

10.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = link
```

This last line wraps the image with a link. In your case it would be

```
10.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = field_link
```

Comment: I want alternate text option for image. Thats why I put that image and alternate text inside a container div. If I put image outside of the container field ('Image and alternate text') my method woks as well.