# Typo3 FCE refer filetype of field uri inside class attribute

Tags: typo3

xI would like to insert the filetype of the inserted file into a a href class:

a href class"icon-filetype-"

i have something like this now:

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = field_uri
10.wrap = icon-filetype-|
```

but than i get the hole url inside the class :D

thans for time

(btw, i used these sites as reference, so maybe i give you a start with it:
[Typo3 FCE refer a field inside a container field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913835/typo3-fce-refer-a-field-inside-a-container-field)
and http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/rs_linklayout/1.3.1/view/1/3/ )

this is the mapping i use:

```
<ul class="section-container">
<li>
<a class="" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Item 1</span><span class="size"></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

did not test this code:

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = field_uri
10.split {
   token = .
   # if you get an different part or some parts added, this optionsplit is wrong
   cObjNum = |*||*| 1 || 2 
   # render nothing means remove this part
   1 = TEXT
   1.value =
   # render only the filetype
   2 = TEXT
   2.current = 1
}
10.wrap = icon-filetype-|
```